# How to load json file in c# from relative path?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, relative-path

I have a problem with localizing the JSON file inside my folder. I have a test class, and in the same directory, I have a JSON file. So what I want to achieve is to retrieve the JSON file with a relative path.

[image]

And the thing that I have tried is this

```
 var jsonString = File.ReadAllText("\\TemplateUrlOk.json");
```

UPDATE

This is the structure of the test project.

[image]

Comment: is it console app or windows app or web app?

Comment: If it's a desktop app or a service, have you set the JSON file to be copied into the build directory when you build and run the application? Also `\\ ` syntax in a windows path is the UNC fileshare format e.g. `\\servername\foldername`. So if the file is supposed to be in the same folder as the executable when the code runs, then you can just supply the filename without any slashes at all.

Comment: what about the usual relative adressing with ` .\  ` ? means:  `var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@".\TemplateUrlOk.json");`

Comment: @FalcoAlexander You'd need an extra backslash to escape the first backslash, or to turn that into a string literal with the @ symbol.

Comment: can you try Application.StartupPath+"\\TemplateUrlOk.json";

Comment: @cbalakus it is a web app

Comment: @ADyson No, I haven`t set the file to be copied. I think this might be the issue. UPDATE: I set the JSON files to be copied to the output directory if newer and the rebuild, but when I debug it still says that the file cannot be found. I also removed the double \

Comment: @CsibiNorbert Since it's a web app then, depending on the type of web app, and where the file is located in the project structure, you may not need to.

Comment: @ADyson I followed what i said in the update message. And I'm getting this error.` 'Could not find file 'E:\Source\KCA2\KCG.EMS\KCG.EMS.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TemplateUrlOk.json'.' `What I'm doing wrong then?

Comment: have you looked if the file _is_ copied to anywhere under \bin\Debug? If so, where? (Sorry I'm less familiar with how ASP.NET Core builds than how .NET Framework does it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be answering my question, hence I found the problem.

@ADyson mentioned that the JSON file needs to be copied in the directory when the project builds, which I did. However, it was in another folder called EmailController and the filename.